# The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. in asp.net c# while uploading xlsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledbcommand

I have an excel file which I am trying to upload but its getting failed with error as below

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.

The error is causing at this line in the below code

**da.Fill(dt);**

And full code is below

```
private void UploadDataForAnyVendor(string strUser)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fluUploadBtn.HasFile)
            {
                string ConStr = "";
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(fluUploadBtn.FileName).ToLower();

                if (ext == ".xls" || ext == ".xlsx")
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadIPFEEData/");

                    //string strFolderName = "INDUS\\";
                    string strAnyFolder = "ANYFOLDER\\";

                    string strDeleteFile = Server.MapPath("~/ANYFOLDER/") + Path.GetFileName(fluUploadBtn.PostedFile.FileName);

                    string newPath = Path.Combine(path, strAnyFolder.ToString());
                    DirectoryInfo objDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(newPath);

                    string day = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss_mm_hh_dd_MM_yyyy");

                    if (!objDirectory.Exists)
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                        newPath = newPath + fluUploadBtn.FileName;
                    }

                    newPath = newPath + fluUploadBtn.FileName;

                    if ((System.IO.File.Exists(fluUploadBtn.FileName)))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fluUploadBtn.FileName);
                    }

                    if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
                    {
                        ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + newPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + newPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";                            
                    }

                    OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

                    if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        mycon.Open();
                    }

                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", mycon);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
                    
                    da.Fill(dt);


                    //loadfile(newPath, ext);

                    string strAssignedStates = string.Empty;
                    strAssignedStates = Convert.ToString(ViewState["States"]);

                    string strOne = strStates;
                    string[] strStateArray = new string[] { "" };
                    strStateArray = strOne.Split(',');

                    string errMsg = string.Empty;

                    int j = 1; string key = "StateNotFoundAlert" + j.ToString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < strStateArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[0]["CIRCLE"].ToString() == strStateArray[i].Trim().ToString())
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                errMsg = "1";
                                dt.TableName = "RecodSet";
                                string xml = ConvertDatatableToXML(dt);
                                mycon.Close();

                                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), key, "alert('File uploaded successfully.!!');", true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string noData = "No data to upload.";
                                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", noData, false);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            errMsg = "0";
                        }
                    }

                    if (errMsg == "0" && errMsg != "1")
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), key, "alert('User is not authorised to upload data for state mentioned in excel report ');", true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string key = "Invalid vendor";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), key, "alert('Invalid file extension !!!');", true);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: There is so much manipulation of file paths going on that it is hard to tell if you end up with the right path or not. You might need to verify that the code is "opening" the file in the expected place and (of course) that there is a Sheet1 in the file.

Comment: @topsail: The `newPath` is the exact path where the file is expected place

Comment: @topsail: also its placing the file properly where it is expected to. The main error is at filling of `dt` . Also there is Sheet1 in the file

Comment: That `HDR=Yes;IMEX=2` looks like it could cause some problems. Have you tried with IMEX set to 1?

Comment: @Ambie: Tried with `1` and getting error as `TThe Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object`

Comment: Can you use your connection to list the sheets and edit your question to include that list. Use `DataTable dt = {connection}.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)` and iterate.